# Fetch API - How Do I Send Query From Front End to Backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, twitter

I need to pass a search query from my front end (in React) to my back end (Express) so that my Twitter API route will grab the correct data.  Here is where I'm hitting the Twitter API.  I was just playing around with a req.query to check out JSON so I know that part needs to be removed.

tweets.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Twit = require('twit');
const config = require('./config');

var T = new Twit(config);

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      let ticker = req.query.ticker;
      T.get('search/tweets', { q: ticker })
          .then(function(result) {
            var tweets = result.data;
            console.log(tweets);
            res.send({tweets});
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('caught error', err.stack)
            res.send({ error: err })
          })
      })

module.exports = router;
```

Also note route is set up like this in express

```
app.use('/tweets', tweets);
```

And here is my front end in React (ignoring the actual search component for now). Just confused as to how I would send a search query

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';


const filterData = (tweet) => {
    return ((!tweet.retweeted) && !(tweet.text.includes('RT @') && ((tweet.in_reply_to_status_id) === null)));
  };

class Twitter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        tweets:[],
    }
   }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData("GOOG");
   }

  getData = (query) => {
     fetch('/tweets?ticker='+query)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => data.statuses)
      .then(statuses => statuses.filter(filterData))
      .then(results => this.setState({tweets:results}))
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <h1>Tweets About </h1>
           {this.state.tweets.map(tweet =>
              <div key={tweet.id}>{tweet.text}</div>
              )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Twitter;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here in this line.

Wrong one

```
fetch('/tweets?ticker={query)') <-- this is wrong
```

Correct one

```
     const filterData = (tweet) => {
    return ((!tweet.retweeted) && !(tweet.text.includes('RT @') && ((tweet.in_reply_to_status_id) === null)));
  };

class Twitter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        tweets:[],
    }
   }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData("GOOG");
   }

  getData = (query) => {

     fetch(`http://localhost:3001/tweets?ticker=${query}`, {method: 'GET', headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => data.statuses)
      .then(statuses => statuses.filter(filterData))
      .then(results => this.setState({tweets:results}))
  }

  renderTweets(){
    if(this.state.tweets){
      this.state.tweets.map(tweet =>
        <div key={tweet.id}>{tweet.text}</div>
      )
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <h1>Tweets About </h1>
           {this.state.tweets ? this.renderTweets(): ''}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Twitter;
```

Use template literals

```
fetch(`/tweets?ticker=${query}`)
```

OR

use normal string

```
fetch('/tweets?ticker='+query)
```

Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more details on how template literals works. Your code should be fine now.

Comment: hey thanks---i've tried your suggestions but still not working--- i get a `(TypeError): Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined` ---on this line `.then(statuses => statuses.filter(filterData))`

Comment: Looks like query param issue is resolved. Ok tell me statuses.filter(filterData) in this line I don't see filterData in your code.

Comment: Looks like statuses is null and thats why you are getting that error

Comment: just updated code (2nd version up top) to include filterData function

Comment: Can you do console.log(statuses) like .then(statuses => console.log(statuses)) and let me know what it prints

Comment: ok i get Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`{this.state.tweets.map(tweet =>`

Comment: See there are lot of issues in your code not just with query param. Where is this.state.tweets.map code? Post your full Twitter component code otherwise it’s difficult to guess and help you here

Comment: oh ...sorry --i added all the code for each of the files.  my mistake.  I will note that everything was working fine when i would look up the twitter api in my server like this localhost:3000/tweets?ticker=$GOOG  ...

Comment: you see that issue because you are not getting data in your fetch api and thats why it is throwing map undefined error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163992/discussion-between-hemadri-dasari-and-john-rogerson).